# Python context manager not cleaning up

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, contextmanager, try-except

When I raise any exceptions inside a context manager the cleanup code is not run. For example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

try:
    raise BaseException()
except BaseException:
    print "bye from except"


@contextmanager
def say_goodbye():
    yield
    print "bye from context manager"

with say_goodbye():
    raise BaseException()
```

Will output:

```
bye from except
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 15, in 
BaseException
```

Notice that the try/except properly catches the exception while the with statement does not.
Is there something I don't understand about how with statements are supposed to work?

You can see the code in a fiddle here: http://pythonfiddle.com/context-manager-failing

---

FYI I'm running python 2.7 on OSX mavericks. Although I've been able to reproduce in many environments so I doubt that has much to do with it.

Comment: This is fully explained in the [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) docs. The whole last paragraph describes exactly how it works, tells you how to use `try/`except` or `try`/`finally`, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to add exception handling yourself:

```
@contextmanager
def say_goodbye():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print "bye from context manager"
```

The above ensures the `finally` block always runs regardless of an exception inside the with block. If you want exceptions to be handled you'll need to catch those and possible reraise them:

```
@contextmanager
def say_goodbye():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    finally:
        print "bye from context manager"
```

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) says:

> If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred. Thus, you can use a try...except...finally statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place.

Also note that `BaseException` is not an `Exception`:

```
>>> isinstance(BaseException(), Exception)
False
```

Your own exceptions should inherit from `Exception`, not `BaseException`.